# Perl - One liner file edit: "perl -n -i.bak -e "print unless /^$id$,/" $filetoopena;" Not working

Tags: perl, file, edit

I cannot get this to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
my $id='123456'; 
my $filetoopen = '/home/user/public/somefile.txt';
```

file contains:

```
123456
234564
364899
437373
```

So...
A bunch of other subs and code

```
if(-s $filetoopen){
     perl -n -i.bak -e "print unless /^$id$,/" $filetoopen;
}
```

I need to remove the line that matches $id from file $filetoopen

But, I don't want script to "crash" if $id is not in $filetoopen either.

This is in a .pl scripts sub, not being run from command line.

I think I am close but, after reading for hours here, I had to resort to posting the question.

Will this even work in a script?

I tried TIE with success but, I need to know alternatively how to do this without TIE::FILE.

When I tried I got the error:

syntax error at mylearningcurve.pl line 456, near "bak -e "

Thanks for teaching this old dog...

Comment: whats the **,** in the regex? Update the question with how you run **perl -n -i.bak -e "print unless /^$id$,/" $filetoopen;** inside your perl script.

Comment: I don't know why the comma is there. I was working from examples. The line is in an if statement. if(-s $filetoopen){perl -n -i.bak -e "print unless /^$id$,/" $filetoopen;
}

Comment: @Jim_Bo - so the line is from a shell script?

Comment: I edited the script to show how I am using.

Comment: remove the comma it serves no purpose for your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all (this is **not** the cause of your problem) `$,` (aka `$OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR`) defaults to undef, I'm not sure why you are using it in the regex. I have a feeling the comma was a typo.

It's unclear if you are calling this from a shell script or from Perl?

---

If from Perl, you should not call a nested Perl interpreter at all.

If the file is small, slurp it in and print:

```
use File::Slurp;
my @lines = read_file($filename);
write_file($filename, grep { ! /^$id$/ } @lines);
```

If the file is large, read line by line as a filter.

```
use File::Copy;
move($filename, "$filename.old") or die "Can not rename: $!\n";
open(my $fh_old, "<", "$filename.old") or die "Can not open $filename.old: $!\n";
open(my $fh, ">", $filename) or die "Can not open $filename: $!\n";
while my $line (<$fh_old>) {
    next if $line =~ /^id$/;
    print $fh $_;
}
close($fh_old);
close($fh);
```

---

If from a shell script, this worked for me:

```
$ cat x1
123456
234564
364899
437373

$ perl -n -i.bak -e "print unless /^$id$/" x1

$ cat x1
234564
364899
437373
```

Comment: Yes, the $ is there I just forgot while typing here.

Comment: single quotes did not help. Same error. I was under the impression that if I used single quotes that $id would not be 123456 but literally $id. I am a noob, thanks for your patience..

Comment: @Jim_Bo - sorry, edited. I mis-read your Q to mean that $id is assigned inside the Perl code, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(-s $filetoopen){
     perl -n -i.bak -e "print unless /^$id$,/" $filetoopen;
}
```

I'm not at all sure what you expect this to do. You can't just put a command line program in the middle of Perl code. You need to use `system` to call an external program. And Perl is just an external program like any other.

```
if(-s $filetoopen){
     system('perl', '-n -i.bak -e "print unless /^$id$,/"', $filetoopen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of the `-i` command line argument can be accessed via [`$^I`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

```
local @ARGV = $filetoopen;
local $^I = '.bak';
local $_;
while (<>) {
   print if !/^$id$/;
}
```